# Paypal V2 PHP Checkout SDK

Tags: laravel, paypal

I`m building an application using Laravel with Paypal PHP SDK, and everything was working normally, but today when I wanted to make some tests on checkout, I faced some errors, Paypal securely login stopped working, and as I checked, it seems that Paypal PHP SDK [Link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) is now deprecated, and we have to use new SDK for API V2 [Link](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK).

I downloaded the new PHP SDK, but from the documentation, they only provided sample on how to create an Order with the SDK, and no sample provided for creating Payments.

My first question, what is the difference between Order V2 and Payment V2?
Question number 2, is there any example for how to create payment with the new PHP SDK? because I need to make the user able to click on purchase button and pay with Paypal with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

1. The v2 SDK uses Orders for the payment approval process (instead of PAYIDs).  'v2 Payments' refer to what you get when you capture/authorize an order i.e. transaction/authorization objects.
2. The way you create a 'Payment' in v2 most simply is you first create an order with intent:capture, and you pass that orderid to the front-end UI https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , and after approval you capture it (equivalent to v1 execute).
3. Capture results in a capture id, which is a v2 payment object (equivalent to a v1 sale id). This id is what will show in paypal.com account, and the only thing you need to persist for accounting purposes.

The changes can seem confusing at first, but the new system *is* better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I got it, but I don`t use fronted javascript, and I will continue on server side, so what I did now, I created an order, then from the response, I received 4 links for [self, approve, update and capture], and I have to redirect the user to the approve URL to continue with the process on Paypal, and if he completed all steps, he will return back to the return_url, is that correct?

Comment: The front-end javascript calls server-side routes. It provides a far superior modern experience, leaving your site loaded in the background, with no redirects. You should not use any redirects in modern design when not needed.

Comment: Specifically the pattern for server-side integrations which in turn call the PayPal REST APIs: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Hi @PrestonPHX, So does it means we must use javascript front-end UI for this v2 SDK?
I am facing same problem. I cannot execute payment. Please advice for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do not need to use the JS, but you should.